# how to generate a PWM carrier wave using relay and discrete time integrator in simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink, pwm

I am trying to generate a PWM carrier wave in simulink using relay block and discrete integrator block, as shown below. The idea is simple. The relay switches on and off at 1 and -1 respectively, generating -4*(switching frequency) at ON and 4*(switching frequency) at OFF. This goes into a discrete time integrator to produce a carrier wave.

[self build model for PWM carrier wave generation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSw21.png)

To verify the validity, the output is compared with the carrier wave generated by the simulink build-in PWM Generator, as shown below. The first pic is my result, second the build-in PWM Generator and the third is the error.
[compare with built-in carrier wave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvC0w.png)
[zoom-in of the result to see the clear phase discrepency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoIDW.png)

The model is running at discrete step (1e-6), and the switching frequency is 800Hz.

[discrete time integrator setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZTQk.png)
[relay setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9e6rB.png)

I want to understand the reason of the error and how to correct the model.